# Parse.com many-to-many with attributes

Tags: many-to-many, parse-platform, pivot-table

I have a many-to-many relation between "Ingredient" and "Recipe". I know I can add and remove object from the relation using

```
var Recipe = Parse.Object.extend("Recipe");
var Ingredient = Parse.Object.extend("Ingredient");

var recipe = new Recipe();
var ingredient = new Ingredient();

ingredient.id = "abcDef1234"; //random

var recipe_ingredients = recipe.relation("recipe_ingredients");
recipe_ingredients.add(ingredient);
```

But this only adds the ingredient. How do I also store a field like "quantity" along with each ingredient added? (Like extra attributes on a pivot table?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can't. This is one of Parse's **many** limitations. You'll have to abandon the builtin relations model, create your own *join table*. That is, create a new object type which has two pointers: the first, the source object; the second, the target. This forms the relation. You can then add fields on this table to act as attributes on the relationship. If you want, you can keep a pointer from the object that originally held the relation, targeting the join table entry.

Of course, once you realise that this doubles the number of requests you're using (each database hit is a "request" apparently), then you start to realise that the Parse database model coupled with their charging model scales about as well as building skyscrapers from matchsticks.

Comment: Each database hit is not a "request" towards your API req/sec limit. As long as you use one of the "include" functions to get the related objects in the same query it is a single API request.

Comment: Until you reach the include depth limit (3); or need (as in this case) to create two items when you really should need to create one (can't do multiple creations in a single request).

Comment: You can save up to 50 objects in a single request (`saveAll(array)`), but it wouldn't work in this case due to them needing to reference each other. You could save the Recipe and the Ingredient in a single `saveAll()` request, then save the join in a second request.